# Как понять с какой стороны от `it` `std::multiset::insert(it,value)` будет вставлен элемент?

Tags: c++, stl, multiset

Допустим, есть итератор `it` в контейнере `std::multiset`. Добавляется новое значение в контейнер - `value`, которое равно значению под итератором `*it`. Логично использовать [`std::multiset::insert(it, value)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/multiset/insert/) для ускорения вставки, но мне нужно знать встал новый элемент до `it` или после

```cpp
std::multiset<T> a;

if (*it == value){
    auto pos = a.insert(it, value);
    //if (it > pos) - то что хотелось бы
    //else
}
```

Вот, как можно реализовать искомый код? Сейчас приходится использовать вариант

```cpp
   if(std::distance(a.begin(), it) > std::distance(a.begin(), pos))
   else
```

Найдётся ли вариант пошустрей?

Итак, мне нужно знать: позиция нового элемента будет до `it` или после?

Comment: а почему вам нужно использовать именно вставку с итератором? Это давольно опасная вещь (может привести к неожиданным последствиям при неправильном использовании)

Comment: вы про псевдокод в комментарии? Так я и не использую, потому что так не работает. Но и `std::distance(a.begin(), it)` весьма тяжёлый вариант.

Comment: спрашиваю конкретно про вставку - `insert` ваш

Comment: Можно подробней, что с ней не так? `it` гарантированно валиден. Как и указано в вопросе - используется для ускорения. В данном случае это константа по вставке (значения совпадают)

Comment: я говорил что что-то не так? По-моему я задал вполне конкретный и простой вопрос

Comment: Ответ на который уже есть в тексте - для ускорения вставки. И да вы сказали, что то-то не так: "Это давольно опасная вещь (может привести к неожиданным последствиям при неправильном использовании)"

Comment: если речь идет об ускорении вставки о каких размерах multiset идет речь? Сколько элементов в среднем эта штука будет занимать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117656/discussion-between-mr-nae-and-andrej-levkovitch).

Comment: Ну и ужасный интерфейс в чате... Напишу это сдесь: Я веду к тому, что по моему стойкому убеждению вы пытаетесь сэкономить на спичках. Устройство деревьев таково, что у них логарифмическая сложность вставкии и чтобы пытаться это дело ускорить нужны основания (чего я не вижу в вашем случае) и прямые руки, так как подобная вставка отрабатывает корректно только если итератор находится на правильной позиции. А иначе это либо не даст эффекта, либо вообще может привести к не верной вставке (по поводу последнего нужно сверяться со стандартом).

Comment: По алгоритму мне нужно именно дерево и итератор в нём, поэтому Это те спички, которые не обсуждаются. И, да, меня устраивает логарифмическая вставка. И да, когда значения не совпадают я знаю с какой "стороны" от `it` будет `pos`. Вопрос только с совпадающими значениями - тут сложность моей проверки вырастает до линейной

Comment: Ну что ж, тогда у вас есть единственный вариант: двигаться влево и вправо от вашего it пока не найдете позицию в которой произошла вставка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом, Stanislav Volodarskiy [указал правильное направление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1223533/214732), оно работает только с C++11.

Что даёт простая вставка значения `std::multiset::insert(value)`?  Стандарт [утверждает](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert), вставка `value` будет в конец последовательности из одинаковых значений, но только начиная с C++11. Для более ранних версий поведение не регламентировано - может встать где угодно в череде одинаковых значений. Сложность `O(log N)`

Вставка `std::multiset::insert(hint, value)` позволяет добавить `value` как можно ближе к `hint`. Если, при проверке *слева* от `hint`, получается вставить `value`, то вставка происходит за `O(1)`, иначе за `O(log N)` ищется ближайшее место. Это справедливо для С++11. Для версий до С++11 утверждается, что за `O(1)` вставка *справа* от `hint`, однако, в [справке по С++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert) так же сказано, что `hint` - всего лишь стартовая позиция поиска (до С++11).

[Эксперименты](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b7f7nE) с разными компиляторами и разными стандартами показали, что:

- вставка происходит слева от `hint` за `O(1)` когда это возможно: `*hint >= value && *prev(hint) <= value`,
- некоторые компиляторы способны сделать вставку за `O(1)` справа когда `*hint < value && *next(hint) <= value`,
- новый элемент вставал максимально близко к `hint`,
- ни один из задействованных в эксперименте компиляторов не захотел сделать вставку справа от `hint` при `-std=c++98`. Тем не менее это не означает, что таких компиляторов нет.

Вывод. Гарантировать, что вставка будет слева от `hint` можно только для С++11. Гарантировать, что вставка будет справа для ранних стандартов - нельзя. "Любимое" место проверки на доступность вставки - слева от `hint`.

Чтобы гарантировать, что новый элемент добавиться строго, скажем, справа от `it` за `O(1)` достаточно в качестве `hint` использовать элемент следующий за `it`:

```cpp
std::multiset<T> a;

if (*it == value) {
    auto pos = a.insert(std::next(it), value);
    //теперь std::distance(a.begin(), it) всегда меньше std::distance(a.begin(), pos)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[В стандарте](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert) сказано что в вашем случае элемент будет вставлен прямо перед `it`:

> inserts value in the position as close as possible, just prior(since C++11), to hint

Код можно поменять вот так:

```
std::multiset<T> a;

if (*it == value){
    auto pos = a.insert(it, value);
    assert(pos + 1 == it);
    // ...
}
```